# Delete Any Instances Past Allowed Number - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-models

Is it possible with Rails to delete anything past a certain limit. For example, if there were 200 posts in a Model post and I wanted to only keep the most recent 100 and delete the old ones, what is the most efficient way to do that? Would it be this? Is there a quicker way?

```
Post.order(date: :desc).last(100).delete_all
```

But this isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you could do it in one query but I would find the date of the last Post you want to keep, then delete all older Posts.

e.g.

```
date_of_oldest_post = Post.order('date desc').offset(100).first.date
Post.where('date < ?', date_of_oldest_post).delete_all
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is ugly like hell, but it will works:

`Post.where.not(id: Post.order(date: :desc).last(100).select(:id)).delete_all`

Answer (score 0):

```
Post.order(:created_at).first(Post.count-100).each.destroy if Post.count > 100
```

1. Order by created_at time, ascending
2. Create an array with the oldest entries exceeding 100 posts
3. Iterate through each post and destroy it